# add a pre roll sound before my sound files in JWplayer free version

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I want to add the same short jingle sound before all my files 
I only have the free version of JWplayer, can someone help me to do that ?

This is my script for now, thank you

```
<script>
    jwplayer("mediaspace2").setup({
        file: encodeURI("<?php echo base_url('media/'.$emission_hero['source_repertoire'].$emission_hero['nom_fichier_son']);?>"),
        width: 'auto',
        height: 30
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

probably not the best way to do it but a simple playlist do what i want so all good:)

```
<script>
        jwplayer("mediaspace2").setup({
            playlist:
                [{
                "file": encodeURI("<?php echo base_url('media/preroll.mp3')?>")},
                    {
                        "file": encodeURI("<?php echo base_url('media/'.$emission_hero['source_repertoire'].$emission_hero['nom_fichier_son']);?>"),
                        }
                ],

            width: 'auto',
            height: 30

        });
</script>
```